# How to phrase this sentence correctly (about possibility)

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, modal-verbs

1. My future self will wonder what could happen if I choose to stay in my current marriage instead.
2. My future self will wonder what would happen had I chosen to stay in my current marriage instead.

I am not sure whether any of them is grammatically correct, or if there is a better way to rephrase the sentence. I am also trying to imply that at the present I am leaning towards leaving the marriage but have not made any concrete decision.

Comment: The first sentence is syntactically valid, but inherently confusing (it seems to be saying that ***if I don't get divorced***, then at some future time I'll be wondering what might happen, which makes little sense to me). The second sentence is syntactically *invalid*, but it's easy to see the intended meaning anyway. Note that the stylised "inversion" ***had I chosen*** is a relatively uncommon usage - most native speakers would use ***if I had chosen*** in such contexts today.

Answer (score 1):

**Past future perfect tense** indicates something that has already completed at a point in the future. *"would have", "should have"*.

> My future self will wonder what **would have happened** had I chosen to
> stay in my current marriage instead.

Comment: Because the reference to a 'future self' implies looking back from a time after the marriage has ended.